# Confusion about cofinality

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm confused about the notion of the cofinality of a **cardinal**. Since I think the source of the confusion is the [Von Neumann cardinal assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment), my first question is:

**Question 0**. Is there an article or book that purposely distinguishes between a cardinal and its associated initial ordinal?

Anyway, for the duration of this question, lets adopt this distinction. Thus we have two order-isomorphic proper classes, $\mathrm{Ord}$ and $\mathrm{Card}$. And although we have retained the identification $[0,\alpha)=\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}$, we have abandoned it for cardinals. Additionally, given cardinal numbers $\mu$ and $\nu$, lets write $[\mu,\nu)$ for the set of all cardinals $\kappa$ with $\mu \leq \kappa < \nu$.

Furthermore, let $x \mapsto \underline{x}$ denote the unique order isomorphism $\mathrm{Ord}\rightarrow \mathrm{Card}$, so for example: if $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal, then $\underline{\omega}$ is the least infinite cardinal. Also, let $\eta : \mathrm{Card} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ord}$ denote the proper class function that maps every cardinal number to its initial ordinal. And finally, for every subset $A$ of a well-ordered set, lets write $\mathrm{ord}(A)$ for the unique ordinal that is order-isomorphic to $A$. So in general, we have that $\mathrm{ord}(A) \in \mathrm{Ord}$.

Now my understanding is that the cofinality $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ of an **ordinal** $\alpha$ is defined as the least ordinal $\beta$ such that there exists a cofinal subset of $\alpha$, call it $B$, such that $\mathrm{ord}(B)=\beta$.

**Question 1**. Under these definitions, how does one define the cofinality of a cardinal number $\kappa$? Is it:

1. The ordinal $\mathrm{cf}\,\mathrm{ord}[0,\kappa)$
2. The cardinal $|\mathrm{cf}\,\mathrm{ord}[0,\kappa)|$
3. The ordinal $\mathrm{cf}\,\eta({\kappa})$
4. The cardinal $|\mathrm{cf}\,\eta({\kappa})|$
5. Something else???

I honestly can't work it out.

Comment: The cofinality of an ordinal is always an initial ordinal, hence, may be regarded as a cardinal. The definition of the cofinality of a cardinal is, in your notation, $\operatorname{cf} \eta (\alpha)$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, thank you!!!

Comment: How are options 1 and 3 different? (I assume the $\alpha$ in 3 and 4 are meant to be $\kappa$)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo In his notation, $[0, \aleph_1)$ denotes $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, \aleph_0 \}$, which is countable.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! OK. Then option 3 is what you want as definition. And option does not always give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! So putting Zhen and Andres comments together, it would seem that 3 & 4 are valid definitions, but 1 & 2 are incorrect. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can formulate two forms of cofinalities:

1. Ordinal cofinality, which is the least order type of an unbounded set.
2. Cardinal cofinality, which is the least cardinality of a partition that all its parts are smaller then the original cardinal.

Some facts that are useful to know:

- Both versions have the property that the resulting ordinal is *always* a regular cardinal. That is, the cofinality of the cofinality is the original cofinality.
- If $\delta$ is an initial ordinal, i.e. a cardinal, then both cofinalities are equal.

We are not interested not usually interested in the cofinality of $\text{ord}[0,\kappa)$, because it will usually not coincide with either the cofinalities above. For example, $\text{ord}[0,\omega_1)=\omega+1$, and its cofinality as an ordinal is $1$. That is *very* uninteresting, and it doesn't tell us much. Whereas knowing that $\omega_1$ is a regular cardinal tells us plenty.

And as for your question $0$. If the same context uses both ordinal and cardinal arithmetics, then there is benefit to using $\aleph_\alpha$ instead of $\omega_\alpha$, to discern the cardinal and ordinal arithmetics. But in many cases people use $\kappa,\lambda,\mu,\nu$ for cardinals and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ for ordinals so it's possible to understand from the context of the letters, Shelah is a prime example and many of his papers begin with this. (Of course they always say whether or not a letter denotes a cardinal or an ordinal.)

Comment: With regards to the two notions of cofinality, is there a third? Namely, the least cardinality of an unbounded subset? And which, if either, of 1 and 2 does this coincide with? Also.... I think dot point 2 is meant to read: "If $\delta$ is an initial *ordinal*." And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo. The third notion is really just the first. Because the least order type is always a cardinal and it is trivially the least cardinality of an unbounded set.

Comment: Gotcha. And I suppose that for all ordinals (indeed, for all partially ordered sets), definition 1 is always less than or equal to definition 2?

Comment: Hm. For ordinals the two are equal, so yes. I'm not sure what happens in the case of partial orders. But in the case of partial orders unbounded sets need not be well-ordered, even if the set is directed. So talking about order-types is slightly awkward. In that case we talk about cardinality.

Comment: Are you sure they're equal for ordinals? It seems to me (and I may have completely misunderstood) that $\mathrm{cf_1}(\omega+1)=1,$ while $\mathrm{cf_2}(\omega+1)=\aleph_0$.

Comment: $\{\omega\}$ is an unbounded set in $\omega+1$. I am fairly sure that singletons have cardinality $1$. :-)

Comment: Really?! I was rather certain singletons had cardinality $2$! But on a more serious note, i still dont get it. $\{\omega\}$ is not a partition of $\omega+1$, nor do its parts have cardinality strictly less than $|\omega + 1|$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant your suggestion for a third cofinality as least cardinality of an unbounded set in a partial order. As I remarked, the second version of cofinality focuses on the cardinality rather than the structure as an ordered set. It will coincide with the first one in the case of initial ordinals, but not necessarily otherwise. Note that the second cofinality accepts only cardinals and $\omega+1$ is not a cardinal.

Comment: Hmmm. Why do you insist on definition 2 being defined only for cardinal numbers? It seems to me that it can accept any set whatsoever...

Comment: Because it discards any structure immediately. So it's really something defined on cardinals, rather than generally sets. Of course one can place any set into that, but it's kind of missing the point behind the definition -- the point of discarding all structure. So we define it for cardinals.

Comment: I guess so. Anyway, now that that's cleared up: the question i was trying to ask all along.... is it true that for all partially ordered sets, definition 3 is less than or equal to definition 2 applied to the cardinality of the set?

Comment: Hm. I want to say yes but I keep getting confused. I think that the answer is "yes, and possibly strictly less".

Answer (score 5):

Here is an ordinal-free way of defining cofinality of a cardinal.

> The **cofinality** of a cardinal $\kappa$ is the least cardinal $\lambda$ for which there exists a set $X$ of cardinality $\lambda$ such that every member of $X$ is a set of cardinality $< \kappa$ and $\coprod_{x \in X} x$ has cardinality equal to $\kappa$.

A slightly cleaner definition is available if you permit cardinal arithmetic:

> The **cofinality** of a cardinal $\kappa$ is the least cardinal $\lambda$ for which there exists a set $X$ of cardinality $\lambda$ and a function $f : X \to [0, \kappa)$ such that  $\sum_{x \in X} f (x) = \kappa$.

Of course, these both compute the same answer as the standard definition (exercise!), but have the advantage of making sense in contexts where the well-ordering principle is not available.

Comment: Actually, I think the previous comment I left here may have been a bit silly. Please disregard it.

Comment: Just to confirm: by $[0,\kappa)$ you're meaning the set of all cardinals $\nu$ such that $\nu < \kappa$?

Comment: Yes. But if $[0, \kappa)$ is the set of all _ordinals_ of cardinality less than $\kappa$, then the answer is the same, provided the well-ordering principle is available.